# tera: Display line number and type of the failure for rendering errors

Tags: rust, tera

I have the following code in Rust using tera template language:

```
    let mut context = Context::new();
    context.insert("adminform", &admin_form);
    let html = match tera.render("change_form.html", &context) {
        Ok(html) => html,
        Err(err) => return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!("Failed to render the template: {}", err))
    };
```

The rendering fails, but the only information I receive is:

```
Failed to render the template: Failed to render 'change_form.html'
```

How can I get a more detailed error? I need to get the line number and exact failure to debug and fix.

Comment: Did you try formatting with `{:?}`?

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful ```Failed to render the template: Error { kind: Msg("Failed to render 'change_form.html'"), source: Some(Error { kind: Msg("Variable `fieldset.classes2` not found in context while rendering 'fieldset.html'"), source: None }) }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error contains more information in its `source`, making this a chained error.

By default, `println!("{}")` only prints the last error of the chain. Printing with `{:?}` (debug-printing) would reveal more information.

There are frameworks that can visually display the entire chain, like [`miette`](https://docs.rs/miette/). Be aware that you need to enable the `fancy` feature of `miette` for this to work.

```rust
// Define some errors which can create an error chain
mod errors {
    use thiserror::Error;

    #[derive(Error, Debug)]
    #[error("MyErrorA: {msg}")]
    pub struct MyErrorA {
        pub msg: String,
        #[source]
        pub source: MyErrorB,
    }

    #[derive(Error, Debug)]
    #[error("MyErrorB: {msg}")]
    pub struct MyErrorB {
        pub msg: String,
    }
}

use miette::IntoDiagnostic;

fn main() {
    let err = Err(errors::MyErrorA {
        msg: "Outer error!".to_string(),
        source: errors::MyErrorB {
            msg: "Source error!".to_string(),
        },
    });

    match err.into_diagnostic() {
        Ok(()) => println!("Success!"),
        Err(e) => {
            let pretty_error = format!("{:?}", e);
            // Do something with the pretty error, like inserting it in a HTML message.
            // In this case, I'll print it.
            println!("{}", pretty_error);
        }
    }
}
```

```
  × MyErrorA: Outer error!
  ╰─▶ MyErrorB: Source error!
```

---

So in your case, I might **guess** that something like the following might work. I can't be sure, though, because your example isn't reproducible for me to test it. So be aware that the following code is untested.

```rust
    let html = match tera.render("change_form.html", &context).into_diagnostic() {
        Ok(html) => html,
        Err(err) => return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(format!("Failed to render the template: {:?}", err))
    };
```